# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll._get_narrow_winmain_command_line

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battlenet-api

I'm experiencing an issue with PlayOnLinux and Wine. I currently run a Linux Mint 18 distribution and I am trying to run the Battle.net application (you know, an HS game is really refreshing when you have to code for long sessions). I finished the installation sucessfully, but at the moment I can't start the application: the first window of the program appears, freezes and then crashes, showing this error:

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-
1-0.d._get_narrow_winmain_command_line called in 32-bit code 
(0x7b43fbe2).
Register dump:
CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
EIP:7b43fbe2 ESP:0033fd64 EBP:0033fdd8 EFLAGS:00200202(   - --  I   - - - )
EAX:7b42ab59 EBX:7b63f8c8 ECX:00000008 EDX:0033fd84
ESI:00000002 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0033fd64:  0033fe00 00000008 7e519b14 80000100
0x0033fd74:  00000001 00000000 7b43fbe2 00000002
0x0033fd84:  7e3ffe77 7e3ffeb2 7e48d931 00dde930
0x0033fd94:  1ef2f623 0132e6c0 7e49c094 0033fdbc
0x0033fda4:  f74d1a8d 7e519b14 7e4c98de 0033fde0
0x0033fdb4:  00000000 00000044 00add244 00dde930
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b43fbe2 in kernel32 (+0x1fbe2) (0x0033fdd8)
1 0x7e3ffe58 in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0 (+0xfe57) (0x0033fe10)
2 0x7e3ff981 in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0 (+0xf980) (0x0033fe60)
3 0x00add44d in battle.net (+0x6dd44c) (0x0033fe60)
4 0x7b46697c call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe78)
5 0x7b467bab in kernel32 (+0x47baa) (0x0033feb8)
6 0x7bc84300 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
7 0x7bc8746d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
8 0x7bc842de RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
9 0x7bc5572e call_dll_entry_point+0x35d() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
10 0xf75aacbd wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
11 0xf75aad7b wine_switch_to_stack+0x2a() in libwine.so.1 (0xff9dd7a8)
12 0x7bc5bb71 LdrInitializeThunk+0x270() in ntdll (0xff9dd7f8)
13 0x7b46e2b8 __wine_kernel_init+0x987() in kernel32 (0xff9de718)
14 0x7bc5caa3 __wine_process_init+0x182() in ntdll (0xff9de7a8)
15 0xf75a90a2 wine_init+0x2a1() in libwine.so.1 (0xff9de808)
16 0x7c000beb main+0x7a() in <wine-loader> (0xff9dec48)
17 0xf73c4637 __libc_start_main+0xf6() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x7b43fbe2: movl    0xfffffff4(%ebp),%ecx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (214 modules)
PE    340000-  3d5000   Deferred        qt5multimedia
PE    400000- 12b1000   Export          battle.net
PE   13d0000- 18b4000   Deferred        qt5gui   
PE   18c0000- 1b6c000   Deferred        qt5quick
PE   1b70000- 1ba6000   Deferred        qt5winextras
PE   1bb0000- 20e2000   Deferred        vivoxsdk
PE   20f0000- 217a000   Deferred        ortp
PE   2180000- 5786000   Deferred        libcef
PE  10000000-1006d000   Deferred        msvcp140
PE  61000000-61029000   Deferred        qt5xml
PE  64000000-640ba000   Deferred        qt5network
PE  65000000-6546c000   Deferred        qt5widgets
PE  66000000-6627b000   Deferred        qt5qml
PE  67000000-6748e000   Deferred        qt5core
ELF 7a800000-7a932000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a932000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7ea000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7ea000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf7000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf7000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c003000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7c37b000-7c400000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7c443000-7c50c000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7c50c000-7c544000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7c510000-7c544000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7c544000-7c54b000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7c54b000-7c556000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7c656000-7c669000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7c669000-7c66d000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7c66d000-7c67a000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7c67a000-7c686000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7c686000-7c68d000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7c68d000-7c691000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7c691000-7c698000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7c698000-7c6be000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7c6be000-7c809000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7c809000-7c81e000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7c81e000-7c8b3000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7c830000-7c8b3000   \               winex11
ELF 7c8b3000-7c8c9000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c8c9000-7c93e000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7c93e000-7c95c000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c95c000-7ca0b000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7ca6b000-7ca6f000   Deferred        libxau.so.6  
ELF 7ca6f000-7ca95000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7ca95000-7cabb000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7cabb000-7cb49000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7cb49000-7cb4e000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7cb4e000-7cba8000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7cba8000-7cbb5000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7cbb5000-7cbe6000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7cbe6000-7ccbd000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7ccbd000-7ccd1000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7ccd1000-7ccdf000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7ccdf000-7cd31000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7cd31000-7cdb8000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7cdc6000-7cdd8000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
PE  7cdda000-7cded000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-
l1-
PE  7cde0000-7cded000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-
l1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
ELF 7cded000-7ce00000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-
1<el
PE  7cdf0000-7ce00000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF 7ce00000-7ce13000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-
0<elf
PE  7ce10000-7ce13000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF 7cf30000-7cf5a000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7cf5a000-7cfa3000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7cfa3000-7cfce000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7cfce000-7d07e000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d0a0000-7d117000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7d0b0000-7d117000   \               ddraw
ELF 7d117000-7d24d000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7d130000-7d24d000   \               wined3d
ELF 7d24d000-7d28b000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7d250000-7d28b000   \               d3d9
ELF 7d28b000-7d29e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-
 0<elf>
  \-PE  7d290000-7d29e000   \               api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-
0
ELF 7d29e000-7d2c2000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d2a0000-7d2c2000   \               imm32
ELF 7d2c2000-7d2f6000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7d2d0000-7d2f6000   \               secur32
ELF 7d2f6000-7d355000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7d300000-7d355000   \               oleacc
ELF 7d355000-7d369000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc<elf>
  \-PE  7d360000-7d369000   \               dhcpcsvc
ELF 7d369000-7d40d000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7d370000-7d40d000   \               urlmon
ELF 7d40d000-7d425000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7d410000-7d425000   \               userenv
ELF 7d425000-7d531000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7d430000-7d531000   \               comctl32
ELF 7d531000-7d621000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d540000-7d621000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7d621000-7d663000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7d630000-7d663000   \               winspool
ELF 7d663000-7d6a8000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7d670000-7d6a8000   \               usp10
ELF 7d6a8000-7d6da000   Deferred        libcrypt.so.1
ELF 7d6da000-7d7bb000   Deferred        libsqlite3.so.0
ELF 7d7bb000-7d80b000   Deferred        libhx509.so.5
ELF 7d80b000-7d81c000   Deferred        libheimbase.so.1
ELF 7d81c000-7d846000   Deferred        libwind.so.0
ELF 7d846000-7d8d2000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10 
ELF 7d8d2000-7d907000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d907000-7d943000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d943000-7d958000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d958000-7d98c000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d98c000-7d9ed000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d9ed000-7da05000   Deferred        libroken.so.18
ELF 7da05000-7da3e000   Deferred        libhcrypto.so.4
ELF 7da3e000-7daef000   Deferred        libasn1.so.8
ELF 7daef000-7db87000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.26
ELF 7db87000-7dcdf000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7dcdf000-7dd26000   Deferred        libgssapi.so.3 
ELF 7dd26000-7dd44000   Deferred        libsasl2.so.2
ELF 7dd44000-7dd54000   Deferred        liblber-2.4.so.2
ELF 7dd54000-7ddaf000   Deferred        libldap_r-2.4.so.2
ELF 7ddbe000-7ddd1000   Deferred        sensapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ddc0000-7ddd1000   \               sensapi
ELF 7ddd1000-7de35000   Deferred        wldap32<elf>
  \-PE  7dde0000-7de35000   \               wldap32
ELF 7de35000-7de48000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7de40000-7de48000   \               psapi
ELF 7de48000-7df8d000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7de60000-7df8d000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7df8d000-7dfaa000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7df90000-7dfaa000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7dfaa000-7dfe9000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7dfb0000-7dfe9000   \               winhttp
ELF 7dfe9000-7e002000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e002000-7e07f000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e010000-7e07f000   \               wininet
ELF 7e07f000-7e0a7000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e090000-7e0a7000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e0a7000-7e0d6000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e0b0000-7e0d6000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e0d6000-7e0ef000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7e0f0000-7e0fa000   Deferred        libheimntlm.so.0
ELF 7e0fa000-7e111000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e111000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7e111000-7e130000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e120000-7e130000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7e130000-7e15a000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e15a000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e15a000-7e214000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e160000-7e214000   \               winmm
ELF 7e214000-7e22f000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e220000-7e22f000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e22f000-7e243000   Deferred        mswsock<elf>
  \-PE  7e230000-7e243000   \               mswsock
ELF 7e243000-7e314000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7e250000-7e314000   \               crypt32
ELF 7e314000-7e349000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE  7e320000-7e349000   \               wintrust
ELF 7e349000-7e35c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-
0<el
PE  7e350000-7e35c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0
PE  7e35c000-7e36f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1 
-1-
PE  7e360000-7e36f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-
1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
PE  7e36f000-7e382000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-
1-0
PE  7e370000-7e382000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-
1-0C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
ELF 7e382000-7e395000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-
0<elf>
  \-PE  7e390000-7e395000   \               api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0
ELF 7e395000-7e3aa000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-
0<el 
PE  7e3a0000-7e3aa000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0
ELF 7e3aa000-7e3c0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1 
-0<
PE  7e3b0000-7e3c0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-
0
ELF 7e3c0000-7e3d9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-
0<elf>
  \-PE  7e3d0000-7e3d9000   \               api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0
ELF 7e3d9000-7e3ee000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-
0<elf>
  \-PE  7e3e0000-7e3ee000   \               api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-
0
ELF 7e3ee000-7e403000   Dwarf           api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-
0<el  
PE  7e3f0000-7e403000   DIA             api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0
ELF 7e403000-7e416000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-
0<elf
PE  7e410000-7e416000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0
ELF 7e416000-7e429000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-
0<elf>
  \-PE  7e420000-7e429000   \               api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0
ELF 7e429000-7e43e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-
0<elf  
PE  7e430000-7e43e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0
ELF 7e43e000-7e52b000   Deferred        ucrtbase<elf>
  \-PE  7e460000-7e52b000   \               ucrtbase
ELF 7e52b000-7e540000   Deferred        vcruntime140<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e540000   \               vcruntime140
ELF 7e540000-7e567000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e550000-7e567000   \               mpr
ELF 7e567000-7e5a2000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e5a2000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e5a2000-7e628000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e5b0000-7e628000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e628000-7e76f000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e640000-7e76f000   \               ole32
ELF 7e76f000-7e7ea000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e780000-7e7ea000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e7ea000-7ea38000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e800000-7ea38000   \               shell32
ELF 7ea38000-7eab4000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7eab4000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eab4000-7ebdc000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7ebdc000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ebdc000-7ed3b000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ebf0000-7ed3b000   \               user32
ELF 7ed3b000-7ed4e000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed4e000-7ed5b000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed5b000-7ed76000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ed76000-7ed80000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef80000-7efd5000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efd5000-7efde000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7efde000-7efe7000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f73a1000-f73a6000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF f73a7000-f73ac000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73ac000-f7562000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7562000-f757f000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75a2000-f7759000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f775b000-f7780000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7782000-f7783000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000004a    0
    0000001c    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001b    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001a    0
00000027 explorer.exe
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
00000035 Agent.exe
    00000048    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f    0
    0000003d    0
    00000039    0
    00000036    0
00000037 wineconsole.exe
    00000038    0
00000050 (D) C:\Program Files\Blizzard 
App\Battle.net.8657\Battle.net.exe
    00000051    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.9.15
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows Server 2008 R2
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-53-generic
```

Why doesn't it works?

Answer (score 1):

Although I tried this using PlayOnMac on a Mac running Sierra OS, I am certain that it should work for Linux. The problem is that Wine is running an unsupported version of Windows by default. In my case this turned out to be Windows XP. You need to change the OS to a higher version. In PlayOnMac 4.2.12:

- Click the Configure gear icon
- Select your desired virtual drive
- Select the Wine tab
- Click Configure Wine
- Select the Application tab
- Change the Windows version (I selected Windows 10)
- Click the Apply button
- Click the Ok button.
- Back in the Wine tab click "Windows Reboot".
- Try to re-install MT4.